# if have a info of user of firebase i want to dcrypt the passwordhash field what json i recive fron firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

if have a info of user of firebase i want to dcrypt the passwordhash field what json i recive fron firebase

i am using python for this i get the info of the perticular user but i dont have the password field as nomal string its is hased but i want to dehash

```
{"kind":"identitytoolkit#GetAccountInfoResponse","users":[{"localId":"Bjowo8qORH1SKqMyoB0OKALH3","email":"sh2329@gmail.com","passwordHash":"UkVEQUNURUQ=","emailVerified":false,"passwordUpdatedAt":1578135815842,"providerUserInfo":[{"providerId":"password","federatedId":"sh2329@gmail.com","email":"sh2329@gmail.com","rawId":"sh2329@gmail.com"}],"validSince":"1578135815","lastLoginAt":"1578135815842","createdAt":"1578135815842","lastRefreshAt":"2020-01-04T11:03:35.842Z"}]}'
```

simply i want that password so i store in my database

Answer (score 1):

`UkVEQUNURUQ=` is just the redacted password hash (no password hashes will be returned via client SDKs). To get the actual password hash, you would need to use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#password_hashes_of_listed_users) to retrieve it with the right IAM permissions.

That said, never store plain text passwords in your database. Firebase Auth already does it for you using the latest security industry standards. You also have the ability to download all your users' hashes whenever you need.

Answer (score 0):

The `passwordHash` field contains a [**hash**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of the user's password, not the actual password itself. There is no way to derive the user's actual password from that hash beyond a brute force attack.

If you want to store the user's password yourself, you'll have to capture its value before passing it to Firebase. Although I highly recommend not storing it yourself, and leaving it to Firebase to store it securely in a way that minimized risk to your users.